# angular js defining module multiple times not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to redefine angular.module multiple times one is for controller and one is for service etc.
TestService is a factory which is defined in test.js and i want to use it in current html page.

HTML

```
<script src="test.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myapp", ['TestService']).controller(
    "MyController", function($scope, $cookies,TestService ) {

<script>
```

Now i have another javascript page where i am trying to write a service.

test.js

```
angular.module("myapp").factory('TestService', function() {
     return {
        sayHello: function(){
            return "Factory says hi;
        }

    } 
});
```

i am getting the error 'TestService' is not available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("MyController", function($scope, $cookies, TestService) {
        // ...
    });
</script>

<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Meaning that you first need to define module (`angular.module("myapp", [])`), then register service on it.

Comment: yes, but is it not required to inject the service inside the square bracket here? i.e  angular.module("myapp", ['TestService']) vs angular.module("myapp", [])

Comment: When you create module you don't inject anything, those are dependent *modules* in brackets, not services. So you could for example create module Test, put your service there and then use Test as a dependency for main module. `angular.module('Test', []).factory('TestService', function() { ... }); angular.module('myapp', ['Test']).controller('MyController', function() { ... })`.